# Ajax.BeginForm retornando PartialView como View

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Boa Noite!
Estou trabalhando em um projeto de Gerenciamento de Leitos.
Em uma determinada View, eu estou exibindo as Enfermarias cadastradas, e para **fins de filtragem**, um campo onde se pode **pesquisar** pelo nome do Departamento ao qual determinada(as) enfermaria(s) pertence(em).
Conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: Botão de Pesquisa]
Para tanto, estou utilizando o ajax Helper `Ajax.BeginForm` para retornar uma PartialView e popular a tabela. O problema é que estou recebendo uma view separada somente com os dados. Já pesquisei aqui no site, algumas pessoas tiveram o mesmo problema e incluíram o Unobtrusive no _Layout, porém já fiz isso. Já verifiquei tudo várias vezes, e não consigo identificar o que está acontecendo.

- No Web.config já está setado para o Unobtrusive para True
- Já incluí o package validate.Unobtrusive
- Como Default o _Layout não carrega o Unobtrusive, já fiz esta correção.
- A minha controller está possui a Action PartialViewResult

Na EnfermariaController tenho:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public PartialViewResult IndexDep(string pesquisa)
{
    return PartialView((_enfermariaAppService.ObterPeloNomeDoDepartamento(pesquisa)));
}
```

Na Index (a da imagem acima) tenho o seguinte código:

```
//AjaxOptions
@{   
    var ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {        
        UpdateTargetId = "tbBody",
        HttpMethod = "Post",    
    };
}
//Formulário 
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("IndexDep", ajaxOpts))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <div class="form-inline">
       @Html.TextBox("pesquisa","", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder="Pesquise pela sigla do departamento" })
       <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="btn btn-info" />
   </div>      
}
//Tabela onde deveria ser repassado a partialView
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        //Cabeçalhos...
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbBody">
        //Linhas...
    </tbody>
```

Desde já, agradeço imensamente à todos que puderem colaborar.
Abraço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certo, conforme seu comentário que esclareceu minha dúvida, você precisa adicionar também o `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax`.

Basta procurar por `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobstusive.Ajax` pelo ***NuGet*** ou no ***Package Manager Console*** e adicionar ao projeto.

Depois adicionar à sua View que contém o *helper* `Ajax.BeginForm` como fez com o *jQuery Validate Unobtrusive*.

Comment: `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` não é o mesmo que `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js`? Ou estou fazendo uma confusão horrível.

Comment: Não são a mesma coisa não. Um é para validação, o outro é necessário para o `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Comment: Havia associado que ambos eram iguais, mas em versões diferentes. Muito obrigado amigo. Já havia procurado em quatro literaturas e não percebi esta minha confusão.  Grato.  Abraços